# How can I merge local master into all local branches?

Tags: git

I have several local branches, and after sometime, I merged all these branches into master, and then I want to merge local master into all local branches.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one single command in git, but the way to do something "for all the branches" is, in a bash session:

```
for BRANCH in `ls .git/refs/heads`; do something $BRANCH; done
```

That could be used for merging:

```
for BRANCH in `ls .git/refs/heads`; do if [[ "$BRANCH" != "master" ]] ; then git checkout $BRANCH ; git merge master ; fi ; done
```

Or for resetting the branch, as suggested in [William](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1965396/william-seiti-mizuta)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14950990/6309):

```
for BRANCH in `ls .git/refs/heads`; do if [[ "$BRANCH" != "master" ]] ; then git checkout $BRANCH ; git reset --hard master ; fi ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the local branches and recreate them. With this, the new branches will be a mirror of the master branch. You can obtain the same result with `git checkout branch-name && git reset --hard master`.

Remember that this can delete some commits. If you don't want that (maybe because these local branches have a remote branch), you will need to do a `git merge`: `git checkout branch-name && git merge master`.

Comment: As far as I know, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

I used VonC's answer from here, but then for some reason `ls .git/refs/heads` stopped resulting all branch names - only two ones were in this folder. So this modified version worked for me after:

```
for BRANCH in `git branch`; do if [[ "$BRANCH" != "master" ]] ; then git checkout $BRANCH ; git merge master --no-edit; fi ; done
```